# Java: Callablestatement.prepareCall turns CALL in SELECT

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, callable-statement

```
String call = "{?= CALL Proc(?)}";

CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(call);

cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DECIMAL, 0);       
cs.setString(2, "String");
System.out.println(cs);

cs.execute(); // <-- ERROR
```

First line of simple MySQL procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dev`@`11.22.33.44` PROCEDURE `Proc`(IN `login` VARCHAR(255), OUT `var` DECIMAL(20,2)
```

.prepareCall turns my CALL into a SELECT (my guess) which mysql considers a Function and gives me a error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: FUNCTION Proc does not exist
```

The System.out gives me:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4CallableStatement@38d060ac: SELECT Proc('flavi')
```

How can I properly call this procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
String call = "{?= CALL Proc(?)}";
```

with

```
String call = "{CALL Proc(?, ?)}";
```

The former syntax is for calling a stored *function*, which you don't have.  You have a stored *procedure*.

You will also want to swap the order of the bind parameters, as parameter 1 is now the `login` string and parameter 2 is the output variable:

```
cs.setString(1, "String");
cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.DECIMAL, 0);
```